# Pulling a value out from array PHP with string

Tags: php, arrays

```
$outp = "[";
for($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {

if ($outp != "[") {
    $outp .= ",";
}
if ($ARRAY[$x]['name'] == "davies") {
    $outp .= '{"name":"' . $ARRAY[$x]["name"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"server_name":"' . $ARRAY[$x]["server"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"uptime":"' . $ARRAY[$x]["uptime"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"bytes_in":"' . $ARRAY[$x]["bytes-in"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"bytes_out":"' . $ARRAY[$x]["bytes-out"] . '"}';
}
}
$outp .="]";

echo ($outp);
```

Hi I'm trying to pull a specific value from the array but I'm not sure how to do it. So I try to use the for loop function together with the if statement. What I'm trying to do is I want to search the value "davies" in the array `[name]` and then from there pull out the rest of the value based on the `array[name]=davies` value only.

Example of my array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [.id] => *2
        [server] => hotspot1
        [name] => davies
        [profile] => davies
        [uptime] => 1d6m42s
        [bytes-in] => 62669946
        [bytes-out] => 459466004
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [.id] => *3
        [server] => hotspot1
        [name] => eric
        [uptime] => 2h14m13s
        [bytes-in] => 6836983
        [bytes-out] => 15648003
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [.id] => *4
        [server] => hotspot1
        [name] => teck
        [uptime] => 1h46m25s
        [bytes-in] => 11847933
        [bytes-out] => 166875279
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [.id] => *5
        [server] => hotspot1
        [name] => andy
        [uptime] => 23h13m38s
        [bytes-in] => 31241731
        [bytes-out] => 321399768
    )
)
```

Comment: Take a look at [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) Also take a look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Your code seems to do (almost) the same as `echo json_encode($ARRAY)`

Comment: As @BartHaalstra wrote: json_encode will do what you want. You probably just need to transform the "server" key in your array to "server_name"

Comment: What is the output of `echo ($outp)`?

Comment: yea i know my echo code almost generate the same as the json_encode($array), is cause i want to manually changet the key structure for the array value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use array_filter to filter values with corresponding criteria you want; the result will return the filtered values;

example:

```
$students = array(
    array('name' => 'julia', 'age' => 15),
    array('name' => 'john', 'age' => 16),
    array('name' => 'carlo', 'age' => 14),
    array('name' => 'arjay', 'age' => 12),
    array('name' => 'francis', 'age' => 11),
    array('name' => 'carlo', 'age' => 15),
);

$filtered_students = array_filter($students, function($row) { 
    if($row['name'] == 'carlo'){ 
        return true;
    } 
});

print_r($filtered_students);
```

result will be:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => carlo
            [age] => 14
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => carlo
            [age] => 15
        )

)
```

noticed that the array still have the original keys on it. If you want to reset the count just do a reassignment;

```
$filtered_students = array_values($filtered_students);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => carlo
            [age] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => carlo
            [age] => 15
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach( $ARRAY as $value ){
    if( $value['name] == 'davies' ) {
        echo $value['server'] . '<br /'>;
        // And anything else you'd want to echo.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which loops through the array and returns the element record which where the record field and value matches your search criteria

```
function returnRecord($Array, $field, $value) {
    foreach ($Array as $record) {
        if ($record[$field] && $record[$field] == $value) {
            return $record;
        }
    }
    return undef;
}

// Test run
$Array = array(
    array('name' => 'davies', '.id' => '*2'),
    array('name' => 'eric', '.id' => '*3'),
    array('name' => 'teck', '.id' => '*4'),
    array('name' => 'andy', '.id' => '*5')
);

$record = returnRecord($Array, 'name', 'davies');
if ($record) {
    echo "NAME: ".$record['name'];
    echo "\n";
    echo "ID: ".$record['.id'];
    echo "\n";
}
else {
    echo "Record not found";
}
```